# How to extend fabric.Object with additional properties in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, fabricjs

I am writing an application using angular and fabricjs. I want to add a property to fabric.Object class.

I found a solution with monkey-patching `fabric.Object.prototype.toObject`
looking like this:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function(toObject){
  return function(){
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this),{
      foobar: this.foobar
    })
  }
})(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
```

The problem is, when I try to set the `foobar` property, I get an error that `Property 'foobar' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

Since it is TypeScript and not just Javascript, do I have to take some additional steps to make it work?